# Trying to call a variable to go back to start of script, but get error: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Tags: python

I'm making a Calculator in python. How would I call back to the start of my script so if they reply `yes` they go to the start again?

```py
import sys

number = input('What is the first number?')
number = int(number)
number2 = input('What is the second number?')
number2 = int(number2)

yes = print("Hello")
yes = number(yes)

task = input('What do you want to do: / for divide, * for multiply, + for addition, - for subtraction?')

if task == "-":
    answer = number - number2
    print(answer)
elif task == "+":
    answer = number + number2
    print(answer)
elif task == "/":
    answer = number / number2
    print(answer)
elif task == "*":
    answer = number * number2
    print(answer, 'is your answer!')

retry = input('Would you like to try again?')
retry = str(retry)

if retry == "no":
    sys.exit
elif retry == "yes":
    yes()
```

Comment: you need a loop.

Answer (score 2):

In order to go to the start of the script if the user types `yes` you would need a `while` loop. If the user does not want to get the new calculation it breaks out of that while loop, and if the user says `yes` it goes back to the start of the loop using `continue` statement as follows:

```
import sys


while True:
    number = input('What is the first number?')
    number = int(number)
    number2 = input('What is the second number?')
    number2 = int(number2)

    yes = print("Hello")

    task = input('What do you want to do: / for divide, * for multiply, + for addition, - for subtraction?')

    if task == "-":
        answer = number - number2
        print(answer)
    elif task == "+":
        answer = number + number2
        print(answer)
    elif task == "/":
        answer = number / number2
        print(answer)
    elif task == "*":
        answer = number * number2
        print(answer, 'is your answer!')

    retry = input('Would you like to try again?')
    retry = str(retry)

    if retry == "no":
        break
    elif retry == "yes":
        continue
```

Comment: upvote for the loop and a tidy up, but the `retry = str(retry)` and the last two lines are also redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this general pattern:

```py
>>> response = 'y'
>>> while response != 'n':
  2     print('Hi! This is your game loop')
  3     response = input('Do you want to try again? (Y/n): ')
Hi! This is your game loop
Do you want to try again? (Y/n): y
Hi! This is your game loop
Do you want to try again? (Y/n): Y
Hi! This is your game loop
Do you want to try again? (Y/n): yes
Hi! This is your game loop
Do you want to try again? (Y/n): wow
Hi! This is your game loop
Do you want to try again? (Y/n): no
Hi! This is your game loop
Do you want to try again? (Y/n): n
```